# Structure program not working

Tags: c++, vector, structure

void main1()
{

```
struct student
{
    string name = "bob";
    int quizs;
    int labs;
    int midterms;
    int finals;
    int classs;
    int grade;
};

student stude;
vector<student>stu;

vector<string>qui{"Quiz 1","Quiz 2","Quiz 3", "Quiz 4","Quiz 5","Quiz 6","Quiz 7","Quiz 8"," Quiz 9","Quiz 10",
"Quiz 11", "Quiz 12"};
vector<string>La{ "Lab1", "Lab2","Lab3", "Lab4", "Lab5", "Lab6", "Lab7", "Lab8", "Lab9", "Lab10", "Lab11", "Lab12",
    "Lab13", "Lab14", "Lab15", "Lab16", "Lab17" };
vector<string>mid{ "Midterm 1", "Midterm 2" };
vector<string>fin{ "Final 1", "Final 2" };

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{

    cout << "please enter your score for " << qui[i] << ": ";

    cin >> stu[i].quizs;



}
```

}

I can't get this code to work. When I try to run it in MIcrosoft Visual studios, I get a nasty line1234 error that says vector subscript out of range.
Somebody Please help.

Comment: You can't simply access `std::vector` elements that don't exist to cause their creation. This is a behavior that belongs to associative containers. You must resize your vector ahead of time or push new elements with methods such as [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Comment: Look at `stu`.  How many elements are in it to start with?

Comment: Please be more specific than "not working"

Answer (score 0):

Your `vector<student>stu` currently has no elements and so you are attempting to assign a value to something that doesn't exist, you could fix this by creating a temporary student and assigning the value to it instead, then push this temp onto your vector.

Something like this:

```
student tempStu;
getline(cin,tempStu.name);
stu.push_back(tempStu);
```

inside of your loop.

Alternatively you could define the elements of your vector, and modify the contents with this:

```
getline(cin,stu[i].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

stu is an empty vector.

Your program will crash as soon as it tries to execute cin >> stu[0].quizs, since stu[0] references the first element of stu which doesn't exist.

To fix this issue

```
vector<student>stu(qui.size(), {}); //stu.size() and  qui.size() must be equal to 12
```